# Ember ArrayController content undefined after init

Tags: ember.js

I have an ArrayController as follows:

```
DashboardController = Ember.ArrayController.extend
  content: []

  xFormatter: (x) ->
    d3.time.format("%m-%d") x

  init: ->
    console.log("dashboardController init")
    @_super()

    y = undefined
    currentDate = undefined
    i = 1

    while i < 30
      currentDate = new Date("12/" + i + "/2011")
      @content.pushObject
        x: currentDate
        y: (Math.random() * 100) / 10

      i++
```

When the app initializes, the controller is created (as indicated in the console) and content is pushed into the array during `init`, but `content` is undefined when I try to access it from elsewhere (e.g. a view). I tried `content: null`, then doing `@set("content", [])` at the start of `init` but got the same result.

The Ember guides say to set an ArrayController's `content` property in my route's `setupController` method to tell it what model to represent, but since this "model" is a really the result of a function, I'm not sure how to go about that. I thought that since `init` is run for each created instances, each instance would get a populated `content` without using `setupController`.

I think the example I pulled this from is using a old approach not suitable for 1.0.0-rc1. How should I restructure this to work?

Comment: It is likely that your init code works as you expect, but the ember framework will likely overwrite the content of your controller. Can you put up a fiddle? I think it will be quite easy how to perform this logic with the setupController hook.

Answer (score 1):

A simple fix ( as of EmberJS 1.0.0rc-3 ) is to define the model in the route to the controller content in cases where it already exists. Like So (pardon the coffee script):

```
App.MyRoute = Em.Route.extend
  model: ->
    @get('controller.content') || App.My.find(query)
```

There was a change in master though, that prevents this from working, so you might need to do

```
App.MyRoute = Em.Route.extend
  model: ->
    controller = @controllerFor('my')
    controller.get('content') || App.My.find(query)
```

Comment: @RamiroJrFranco As an Ember novice who doesn't know the conventions yet, the coffee script is kind of obscuring this answer...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it seems that the trick is to move the code that generates the values to the `model` hook of the route, then use the `setupController` hook to set the controller's `content`. The only thing I don't like about this is that the data is generated every time there is a transition to the route (since the `model` and `setupController` hook are called each time). I'd like to have it calculated once and cached. I suppose the way to do this would be to create an Object that either creates new data the first time or returns the cached data, then call on this Object in the `model` hook.

Comment: The model hook is just called when entering a route via URL. Afterwards you are supposed to use transitionTo, which would not need to "generate the data" every time.